# How to debug PHP with Xdebug 3.1.5 to a remote server without php.ini access

Tags: php, ssh, xdebug

I'm trying to use Xdebug 3.1.5 that is installed on the server to be able to see the stack trace, but I'm not able to connect / see any debugging info.

I tried following several instructions online to SSH into the server with commands like `ssh -R 9003:localhost:9003 username@username.com`, but still had no luck.

I locally enabled using all / a combination of these settings to override the php.ini:

```ini
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('xdebug.mode', 'develop,debug');
//ini_set('xdebug.client_port', '9003');
//ini_set('xdebug.start_with_request', 'trigger');
//ini_set('xdebug.discover_client_host', true);
//ini_set('xdebug.client_host', 'localhost'); // I also tried switching this with my own IP
//ini_set('xdebug.show_error_trace', 1);
```

Still no luck even after locally overriding with SSH. Any insight would be appreciated!

[image: screenshot of Xdebug phpinfo()]

Comment: What is the relation to SSH, other than that you simply don't have SSH access? That's kind-of confusing in your question. In any case, if the module is loaded, you can use it, if it isn't, you can't. If it is loaded, you can run PHP with some environment vars to enable different functions, that's all documented. However, if you have any kind of shell access, you could as well specify a different `php.ini` on the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make any settings to see Xdebug's stack traces.

That comes automatically with the default setting of `xdebug.mode=develop`.
You don't need to do anything with clients, etc.

If you need **debugging**, than your SSH command is needed, but you need to be able to change the `php.ini` file to enabled `debug` mode with `xdebug.mode=debug`. If you can't change your `php.ini` file, then you can't change Xdebug's modes.

Comment: I see. is there any reason I'm not seeing the stack traces then on xDebug on develop for this remote server?